# Access subclass property from super class

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a class that extends UIViewController called HorizontalModal, which, among other things, I want to automatically generate a back button on each view that extends it. If I put the code to draw the back button in the `viewDidLoad` method for HorizontalModal, nothing shows up. But when I put that same code in the `viewDidLoad` method for the class that inherits from HorizontalModal, the button shows up fine.

E.g:

```
self.backButton = [[BackButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:self.backButton];
```

Seems to me that I'm missing something about class extension and inheritance in objective C. Clearly `self.view` in HorizontalModal and `self.view` in the child class refer to two different things. So is there a way to keep that method in the HorizontalModal class, but be able to add the back button to the child class view? IE, can I access a sub-class property from a super class? Or is there a different way of doing this (maybe with categories)?

Thanks

Comment: View controllers don't have a `-drawRect` method because they're not views and don't draw anything. Perhaps you mean that `HorizontalModal` extends `UIView`?

Comment: Are you by chance trying to implement something which can be implemented with NavigationController, once a new controller is pushed, a back button is provided to pop to previous controller ?

Comment: Sorry, meant viewDidLoad. And no, I don't want to use the built-in navigation controller because I don't get full control over the UI (IE, I can't style the back button how I want, and I can't style the top bar how I want). Regardless, even if I did, my question is how I can set up a super and sub class in such a way that the super can access the sub class' view.

Comment: @Caleb has a good answer below, but you should look to use a navigation controller and customise with the UINavigationBar appearance delegate where you can change both the bar and the back button appearance.

Comment: @Wain I agree -- it's not hard to customize the appearance of the nav bar and buttons. But I think the OP's broader question is about the relationship between classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I put the code to draw the back button in the viewDidLoad method
>   for HorizontalModal, nothing shows up. But when I put that same code
>   in the viewDidLoad method for the class that inherits from
>   HorizontalModal, the button shows up fine.

It sounds like your subclass's `-viewDidLoad` isn't calling it's superclass's `-viewDidLoad`, like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // subclass-specific view setup stuff here
}
```

That allows the superclass's version of `-viewDidLoad` to do its thing first, followed by whatever the subclass needs to do.

> can I access a sub-class property from a super class? Or is there a
>   different way of doing this (maybe with categories)?

If the superclass needs some method that every subclass is expected to provide, then you should put that method in the superclass and let subclasses override it. Normally, the subclass's implementation of the method calls the superclass's version, but if that's *required* then you should document that fact.

The same is true for properties: if your superclass needs to access some property of the subclass (e.g. `backButton`), the superclass should define that property itself. The subclass is then free to change the value of the property or even provide different property accessors, and code in the superclass that uses the property will just work. In general, the superclass shouldn't have to know anything about its subclasses.

So, to be more concrete, let's say you have `MyModal`, a subclass of `HorizontalModal`:

```
@interface HorizontalModal : UIViewController

@property(strong) UIView *backButton;

@end

@implementation HorizontalModal

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.backButton = [[BackButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.backButton];
}

@end    

@interface MyModal : HorizontalModal
//...
@end

@implementation MyModal

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // more code specific to MyModal's view hierarchy
}

@end
```

Now the `-viewDidLoad` method of `HorizontalModal` will be able to access the `backButton` property, even if `MyModal` has changed the value of the property or overridden the accessors. Remember that `self` points to the exact same object in both versions of `-viewDidLoad`, so both versions have access to the same information.

Comment: Ha, could have sworn I did that, but I guess I missed it. Thanks.